# Uso do % em variáveis

Tags: sql, c, string, shell-script

Não consigo entender para que serve este símbolo em uma variável, vejo seu uso em alguns pontos em códigos em SQL, Shell Script, C. Para que serve?

Por exemplo um uso desse símbolo em Shel Script:

```
DATA=$(date +%H)
```

A váriavel `DATA` recebe a *(data atual+ %H)*

Não entendo o que é o `'%'`

Comment: Depende da linguagem. Geralmente é usado como o operador `MOD`, mas isso não tem relação com variáveis. Nunca vi este símbolo em uma variável no Java. Tem como dar um exemplo?

Comment: Em geral isto é `Mod` que é resto da divisão, por exemplo 8 % 3 = 2. Isto é matemática e não programação, sem um exemplo é impossível dizer "o que ele está fazendo".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em Shell Script este é um indicador de formatação, então ele pegará o resultado de `date` e aplicará o formato que o programador estabelecer logo a seguir, no caso o `%H` indica que deseja pegar apenas a hora. O símbolo `%`, neste contexto, é apenas para indicar qual é o padrão que deseja, não ter ambiguidade com letras normais.

Claro que em outras linguagens existem coisas parecidas. É um caractere de *escape* indicado que o que vem a seguir é um código de formatação e não um caractere normal a ser exibido.

Isso não é usado em variáveis e sim em literais *string*.

Comment: Era isso que era minha dúvida! Muito Obrigado!

Comment: @MatheusRambo legal, agora você pode votar em tudo no site também.